# How to add margin or padding to borders?

Tags: html, css

`<span class="border-bottom border-danger"> </span>`

I would like this border to have a margin or padding added, as in the code it's being used for it is clipping into the images. How would I go about doing that? I know there is a code for margin but I can't seem to get it working.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on what you are asking for or show us what you have tried? You should be able to add padding/margin to that element...

Comment: Can you post a fuller example as a code snippet? 

You shouldn't have an image inside of a span, if that's what you are doing. 

Also, take a look at the box model https://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/ the difference between inline and block elments; https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we can add `margin` to span element we should add `display:block` or `display:inline-block;`.

> **Margin** properties specify the width of the margin area of a box. The `'margin'` shorthand property sets the margin for all four sides while the other margin properties only set their respective side. These properties apply to all elements, but vertical margins will not have any effect on non-replaced **inline elements**.

I added bootstrap margin as `m-2` and padding as `p-2` and also add `d-inline-block`

More information about [bootstrap spacing](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/spacing/):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

<span class="border-bottom border-danger p-4 m-2 d-inline-block">This is Span</span>
```

Comment: **Note**: if you are adding margin then add display `block` or `lnine-block` to span. Because span is inline element so doesn't take the margin.

Answer (score 0):

You can add padding and margin to the `<span>` like so:

```
border-bottom{
    margin:auto;
    padding:10px;
    border-bottom:1px solid black;

}
```

Result:

```css
.border-bottom{
  margin:auto;
  padding:10px;
  border-bottom:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<span class="bottom-border border-danger">Hello World!</span>
```

**margin** is a pretty fun thing to play with, for you can align things to the center like so:

```css
.border-bottom{
  width:50%;
  margin:auto;
  padding:10px;
  border-bottom:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<span class="border-bottom border-danger">Hello World!</span>
```

Comment: span elements can have borders, adding the div is superfluous

Comment: @justinw My mistake.